# How to share text/photos/videos into Instagram in ios

Tags: ios, instagram

I want to share text/photos/videos into Instagram. I am searching this for a long time but i didn't get any proper documentation. If anybody knows about share on instagram please let me know.

Comment: using below code you can post photo but this code will open camera and then clicked photo will be uploaded from your app to instagram.    NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=1"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}

Answer (score 2):

[Instagram Media Endpoints](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/)

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>
> Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos
>   from within the app. However, in the future we may give whitelist
>   access to individual apps on a case by case basis.
>
> We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading
>   from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the
>   Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to
>   ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our
>   platform.

Maybe you can try a hook: http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/ or https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *dic;    

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/test.igo"];

NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];
//    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", screenshot]];

self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
self.dic = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
self.dic=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
self.dic.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Here Give what you want to share" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
[self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView: self.view animated: YES ];


- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate {
UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;
return interactionController;
}
```

It works for me. Hope it helps you.