# Video upload with Instagram API now allowed?

Tags: ios, video, instagram

According to the Instagram [documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/), Instagram only allows API uploads for images (JPG, PNG).

A new iPhone app called Cinamatic allows users to upload videos to Instagram after loging in to the Instagram via Cinamatic.

Is video upload via the Instagram API now allowed? There is no mention on the public documentation.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155042/how-to-share-text-photos-videos-into-instagram-in-ios)  there might be the option for a white list of developers with access to the video uploads via the API. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017266/posting-video-on-instagram-using-hooks might be helpful in your case.

Comment: Thank you, this is what everybody does but it sucks in terms of UX. After some research i found out that Istagram for photos. That happened a few years ago. After that trial, 3rd party API uploads were released. Cinamatic is a Hipstamatic app too. I'm guessing Instagram is trying the same thing but with video API uploads now. Time will tell.

Answer (score 0):

**At this time, uploading via the API is not possible.**

following reasons:

Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos from within the app.
We want to fight spam & low quality photos.

Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our platform.

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

I also check this link.

[Posting video on instagram using hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017266/posting-video-on-instagram-using-hooks)
It also doesn't work properly for me.