# Using Instagram API to push content to instagram

Tags: image, api, video, instagram

Is it possible to push a picture or video to instagram using their API?

Answer (score 0):

Instagram does not permit publishing photos/videos via their API.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram is in the process retiring their API in favor of Facebook's Instagram Graph API. In January 2018 they have added image publishing and then in December 2018 - videos. It only works with Instagram business profiles. I've provided a fairly thorough details on this subject here [Video upload with Instagram API now allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572298/video-upload-with-instagram-api-now-allowed/54472037#54472037)